# Why navigation buttons do not light up anymore on my Lumia 830?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-830, navigation-key

Since I upgraded my Lumia 830 to Windows 10 Mobile it seems that the capacitive navigation key buttons do not light up anymore.

I tried to search a way to light them up in the settings, but there is not.

I remember that they do not light up while the phone was in battery save mode on Windows Phone 8.1, but the buttons do not light up anymore even if phone is fully charged.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on my Lumia 830. Is there any workaround? The navigation keys work, but the keys don't light up. I've trued soft resets a coupe of times but without success. Thanks
Arun

Comment: @arun they don't light up even in a *dark* environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that the capacitive navigation key buttons light up by themselves when the phone senses a *dark* environment.

In order to do that the phone uses the frontal sensor near the Nokia logo: if you try to cover it with your finger the buttons will light up in a second.